# How to prime factorise rational numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, factorization

I'm aware of the built-in FactorInteger command for finding the prime factorisation of integers. Is there a convenient way of determining the same thing for a rational number, where the prime factorisation is done for the numerator and denominator separately?

I'm currently using the Numerator and Denominator commands to extract the integers on the numerator and denominator and prime factorising them separately, but this is long-winded and inelegant.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `FactorInteger /@ NumeratorDenominator[frac]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I look at https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FactorInteger.html

and I click on the orange Details and Options then I see

FactorInteger also works on rational numbers.
The prime factors of the denominator are given with negative exponents.

So `FactorInteger[25/27]` returns `{{3, -3}, {5, 2}}` with the -3 indicating that was from the denominator and the 2 indicating that was from the numerator.

If that isn't enough then you might write your own `facInt` function that does the factorization that you may be doing by hand now.

Do you need something more than that?